# Simple calculator in F# using regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex, f#, mono

I have been asked to create a simple calculator by my teacher (one that supports +, - , * and / ). It should take user input and print the result. It should run forever and save the last calculated result.

I would like to do it by using regular expressions, as I have recently been introduced to this, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.
This is what I have created, but it doesn't work.

```
let getInput () =
    System.Console.Write ("give input: ")
    let s = System.Console.ReadLine ()
    s 

let simpleCalc () =
let numb1 = "[0-9]*"
let numb2 = "[0-9]*"
let operator = "[+-*/]"
while true do
    let s = getInput ()
    match s with
        | "([0-9]*)([+-*/]?)([0-9]*)" [ int1; operator; int2 ] -> int1 operator int2
        | _ -> printfn "thas no simple maf"
```

Comment: First off `[+-*/]` says match the ASCII characters between `+` and `*`, so `+,-.`. You need to either escape the `-` or put it at the beginning or end of the list.

Comment: You seem to be using pattern matching instead of regular expressions. You need to use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for those answers guys. I see now that I have mixed up two of my ideas. I would like to not have to define numb1, numb2 and operator in the beginning, but I am unsure how the syntax is to be used. Do you have any help here? I don't actually use the definitions in the beginning for anything.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use regular expressions somewhere. One way to do this, which is quite close to what you were writing, is to define an active pattern that succeeds if the input matches a given regular expression and returns the matched groups as a list:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let (|Regex|_|) regex input = 
  let res = Regex.Match(input, regex)
  if res.Success then Some (List.tail [for g in res.Groups -> g.Value])
  else None
```

A simple evaluator for basic arithmetic can then be implemented as:

```
let s = "123*5"
let ops = dict [ "+", (+); "-", (-); "*", (*); "/", (/)]
match s with
| Regex "([0-9]*)([\+\-\*\/])([0-9]*)" [left; op; right] -> 
    ops.[op] (int left) (int right)
| _ -> -1
```

Note that we need to turn the string representation of an operator into an F# function that we can call somehow - so I defined a simple lookup table using `dict`.